# React with preact-signal doesn't rerender component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, signals

Very simple project to test signal capabilities, but doesn't seem to be re-rendering component.
Although the value of the properties is changing (can be seen via console.log), the value doesn't update at the page view.
Not only setInterval doesn't update it, even the button onClick handler also doesn't update the value at page.
How to fix that?

Component code:

```
import { signal,computed } from '@preact/signals-react';


const name = signal("Name")
const count = signal(0);
const double = computed(() => count.value *2);

setInterval(() => {
  //console.log("function called");
  //name.value = Math.random()
  //console.log(name.value);
}, 500)

//the property is updateting here, it can be seen on the page view.
name.value = "New value 1";


export function Comp() {

    console.log("Render Comp");
    
    return (
        
        <div>

            <h2>Name - {name.value}</h2>  
            <button onClick={()=>{name.value="blablabla";      console.log(name.value)}}>Change</button> 

            <button onClick={()=>{count.value++;console.log(double.value)}}>
                {count.value} x 2 = {double}
            </button>                     

        </div>
        
            
    );

    }
```

App.js code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Comp } from './components/Component';



function App() {

  console.log("Render App");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Comp></Comp>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-signals",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, in your package.json file @preact/signals-react is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody is having the same issue - just delete all node_modules and reinstall everything, it helped in my case.

Comment: I wish I'd see this 3 days before :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please do checkout: [Signals Doc](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/#:%7E:text=we%20can%20let%20Preact%20do%20all%20of%20the%20work%20for%20us%20by%20using%20the%20count%20signal%20directly%20in%20JSX)

And here's how you fix this:

```
import { signal, computed } from '@preact/signals-react';


const name = signal("Name")

const count = signal(0);
const double = computed(() => count.value * 2);

setInterval(() => {
  //console.log("function called");
  //name.value = Math.random()
  //console.log(name.value);
}, 500)

//the property is updateting here, it can be seen on the page view.
name.value = "New value 1";


export function Comp() {

  console.log("Render Comp");

  return (

    <div>

      <h2>Name - {name}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => { name.value = "blablabla"; console.log(name.value) }}>Change</button>

      <button onClick={() => { count.value = count.value + 1; console.log(double.value) }}>
        {count} x 2 = {double}
      </button>

    </div>


  );

}
```